# Microservice blocked user persist in db and verify in other micro services

Tags: spring-boot, database-design, microservices, blacklist

**Description of our project**

We are following micro services architecture in our project with database per service. We are trying to introduce blacklist function to our services which means if some user blacklisted to enter system, they can't use any of our micro services. We have multiple entry/exit points to our micro services such as gateway service (this gateway service will be used by frontend team), websocket message receivers, multiple spring schedulers to process the user data.

**Current solution**

We persist the blacklist users in db and exposed as an endpoint and we can name this as access service. Persisting this blacklist users to the database will be done by support team by calling the access service blacklist create endpoint. So whenever we receive a request from frontend, in gateway we will use the access service to check if the current user is present in the blacklist db, if it's blacklisted then we will block further access. The same goes to whatever message received from schedulers or websocket notifications i.e for example for each call we check whether the user is blacklisted.

**Problem statement**

We have 2 websocket notification receivers, multiple schedulers which will run for every 5 minutes which intern wants to access the same blacklist access service. Because of this we are making too many calls to our access service and causing this to be a bottleneck.

How do we avoid this case?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to the blocklisting problem.

First you could have one service with a blocklist and for every incoming request for every service you would do an extra call to blocklist service. Clearly, this is a huge availability and scalability risk.

Second option is push based: the blocklist service keeps notifying all other services about blocklisted users. In that case, every service can make a local decision to process a request.

The third option is to bake expiration into user sessions. Every session has three elements: expiration, access token and refresh token. Before expired every service will accept requests with valid access tokens. If an access token is expired, then the client has to get a new one by contacting a token service. That service will read refresh token and check if the user is still active and if that's the case - a new access token will be issues.

The third option is the one widely used. Most(all?) cloud providers have shorted lived credentials for this specific goal - to make sure an access can be revoked after some time.

Short lived credentials vs a dedicated service is a well known trade-off; you could read more details about very similar problem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_revocation_list

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the answer. I will go through it. :)